# DenseNet in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am fairly new to tensorflow and I am interested in developing a DeseNet Architecture. I have found implementations from scratch on Github. I was wondering if the tensorflow API happen to implement the dense blocks. Is tensorflow's tf.layers.dense the same as the dense blocks in DenseNet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `tf.layers.dense` implements what is more commonly known as a fully-connected layer, i.e. the basic building block of multilayer perceptrons. If you want dense blocks, you will need to to write your own implementation or use one of those you found on Github.